# OpenERP 7 - Add another status to account.invoice workflow

Tags: workflow, odoo

I wanted to add another status ("advanced") to account.invoice's workflow, between "open" and "paid".
So I inherited the module with

```
class advance_invoice_workflow(osv.osv) :
    _name = 'account.invoice'
    _inherit = "account.invoice"
    _columns = {
    'state': fields.selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('proforma','Pro-forma'),
        ('proforma2','Pro-forma'),
        ('open','Open'),
        ('advanced','Advanced'),
        ('paid','Paid'),
        ('paid_advanced','Paid advanced'),
        ('cancel','Cancelled'),
        ],'Status', select=True, readonly=True, track_visibility='onchange',
        help='* The \'Draft\' status is used when a user is encoding a new and unconfirmed Invoice. \
            \n* The \'Pro-forma\' when invoice is in Pro-forma status,invoice does not have an invoice number. \
            \n* The \'Open\' status is used when user create invoice,a invoice number is generated.Its in open status till user does not pay invoice. \
            \n* The \'Paid\' status is set automatically when the invoice is paid. Its related journal entries may or may not be reconciled. \
            \n* The \'Cancelled\' status is used when user cancel invoice. \
        '),
    }
```

and declared the status in the XML file by making

```
    <record id="act_advanced" model="workflow.activity">
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="account.wkf" />
        <field name="name">advanced</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">set_advanced()</field>
    </record>
```

So I have two transitions:

- the first one from open to advanced,

  ```
  <record id="t2" model="workflow.transition">
      <field name="act_from" ref="account.act_open" />
      <field name="act_to" ref="act_advanced" />
      <field name="trigger_model">account.move.line</field>
      <field name="trigger_expr_id">move_line_id_payment_get()</field>
      <field name="condition">test_advanced()</field>
      <field name="signal">button_confirm_advance</field>
  </record>
  ```
- the second one from advanced to paid

  ```
  <record id="t1" model="workflow.transition">
      <field name="act_from" ref="act_advanced"/>
      <field name="act_to" ref="account.act_paid"/>
      <field name="trigger_model">account.move.line</field>
      <field name="trigger_expr_id">move_line_id_payment_get()</field>
      <field name="condition">test_paid()</field>
  </record>
  ```

From an external module, that does not inherit from account.invoice, but that refers to it, I want to send the signal to the workflow to move from "act_open" to "act_advanced".
So I added a button with name="button_confirm_advance" that binds this action:

```
def button_confirm_advance(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    context = context or {}
    for invoice in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        wf_service = netsvc.LocalService("workflow")
        self.write(cr, uid, [invoice.id],{})
        wf_service.trg_validate(uid,'account.invoice',invoice.id,'button_confirm_advance',cr)   
    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

All variables are correct, but the trg_validate returns False.
What am I wrong?

Thanks,
Patrizio

Answer (score 0):

I solved delegating the flowchart management to another class that inherits from account.invoice

```
class advance_invoice_account_ui(osv.osv) :
    _name = 'account.invoice'
    _inherit = "account.invoice"
```